Duplicate Resources error on generating singed apk with react native by using @viro-community/react-viro
I was facing duplicate resources error on generating singed apk with react native by using @viro-community/react-viro in Viro3DObject when using objects & mtl files from local directory inside project or url.
Error shown in image


I was stuck to this error for almost a week and the solution i got was a small mistake done by me.
I was getting .OBJ & .MTL files from a directory name Modals and the names of files were as under
coralchair.mtl &
coralchair.obj

And I renamed one of file from them like this
coralchair.mtl
coralchairObject.obj

then
clean build 

Now Again generate signed APK using command line or android studio.
this thing resolved the error because while generating build both files were being used as resources and having same name of files was causing conflict.
